# setting the environment path permanently

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch-file

I want to make a batch file for setting the %PATH% environment variable permanently - ie adding a value to the path permanently (in Windows XP).

Comment: i want to make a batch file (using cmd commands)

Comment: if so then I think this belongs on ServerFault. Or is writing a .BAT file considered programming? :-)

Answer (score 5):

On more recent OSes you can use `setx` which allows pretty fine-grained control as for where the variables are stored. Not available on XP, though, unless you install the [Windows Server 2003 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6ec50b78-8be1-4e81-b3be-4e7ac4f0912d&DisplayLang=en).

Comment: SETX works but the syntax is really picky and so its easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Yes, `setx` is not a drop-in replacement for `set`, despite the similar name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use vbscript (or command line reg) to change the PATH environment variable

eg  vbscript

```
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strReg = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path"
    strSetting = WshShell.RegRead(strReg)
    strNewSetting = strSetting&";c\test"  'insert path to current PATH
    WScript.Echo strNewSetting
    WshShell.RegWrite strReg, strNewSetting
```

Comment: This is what programmers looking for this question will want to find.  The accepted answer is a ServerFault (admin/batchfile) answer not a programming answer.

Answer (score 0):

My-Computer - Properties, Advanced system settings -> environment variables.
Set it there.
(I hope that I got the right path here)

Comment: you are missing a right-click (people will double-click on my computer by default) and the tab is named "advanced". another way: start menu/control panel/system then advanced/environment variables. of course this works only if the user uses classic view in the control panel...

Comment: COuld you anser me how to optain exactly the result you describe in your answer, but doing it from a script file?

Comment: something like set path=%path%;new_path

Comment: that would last until you exit from that command prompt session. The question said "permanently". Setx (on systems that have it) works like SET but it's permanent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setx.exe to set environment variables from a batch file or command line. I believe it's included with Vista and 7. For XP, you can find it in the [SP2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en).