# Node.js azure installation

Tags: node.js, azure

I have create virtual machine in azure cloud. Then I install 64 bit nodejs with msi.
I am trying to run node js in powershell. I am getting following error.

How can I fix this?

```
PS C:\Program Files\nodejs>
PS C:\Program Files\nodejs> node
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is the Node.js folder set in your PATH variable?

Comment: I didnt find mycomputer icon or start button in azure server, so I didnt set PATH.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using Windows Server 2012. You will find everything in the Control Panel. If you want to use the shell instead follow the post from @Zugwalt.

Answer (score 1):

Node was likely not set to be in your execution path by default. Try [adding it to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

And then running it:

```
node
```

If that works go ahead and add it to your path permanently using [setx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678729/setting-the-environment-path-permanently).